# Add a [deleted] tag to links in chat that are 10k+

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

When in chat, there's quite a few links flying around that are deleted, and only viewable (well, without the edit trick) by 10k+ rep users or those with access to mod tools. Since the links are shortened to just `stackoverflow.com/questions/...`, would it be worth it to indicate that the question being linked to is a (sort of) dead-link to lower rep users?

[image]

For this, I simply edited the HTML of the page directly to show this. I know that the SE engine knows the status of a question/answer, so it would be a simple check and a HTML addition, but is it worth the query change?

Actually, does the chat engine even check the question or follow the link?

[image]

<sub>(To the devs: cvhelper-processed is a class added by the [cv-pls](https://github.com/cv-pls/cv-pls) userscript that checks for `[tag:cv-pls]` and oneboxes links)</sub>

Comment: +1 ...that would be less annoying for <10k user

Comment: Whenever people talk about an interesting question and link to it in chat I get all excited and click it...only to find out it was deleted. Each time I die a little inside =o(

Comment: afaik the question/answer is "followed" when the link appears on its own.

Comment: What's "the edit trick"?

Comment: @slhck many questions here mention it: if you have the retag privilege, you can go to `http://<site>/posts/<id>/edit` and view it.

Comment: @Hiroto: That's gone now iirc.

Comment: @Manishearth the privilege is there, and you can still do it with 500+ rep.

Comment: If they just put the link on a message itself it will only onebox if not deleted. Otherwise, chat is not going to care

Comment: @random pretty much any link to a deleted question i've ever seen in chat has been accompanied by commentary. For 10k+ users, it's not an issue whatsoever, but for <10k we often either have to ask the 10k+ guys to screenshot, or do the edit trick if 500+ rep. It seems like just an `Engine.Chat.GenerateLink(MarkdownObject link)` (guessing :p) change, but I'm waiting to see if a dev responds. It's mostly just a QoL change for users without access to mod tools.

Comment: What about (exactly not) oneboxed links of that sort?